# BDD and outside-in approach, how to start with testing

Tags: testing, tdd, mocking, bdd

All,

I'm trying to grasp all the outside-in TDD and BDD stuff and would like you to help me to get it.

Let's say I need to implement Config Parameters functionality working as follows:

- there are parameters in file and in database
- both groups have to be merged into one parameters set
- parameters from database should override those from files

Now I'd like to implement this with outside-in approach, and I stuck just at the beginning. Hope you can help me to get going.
My questions are:

What test should I start with? I just have sth as follows:

```
class ConfigurationAssemblerTest {

    @Test
    public void itShouldResultWithEmptyConfigurationWhenBothSourcesAreEmpty() {
        ConfigurationAssembler assembler = new ConfigurationAssembler();            
        // what to put here ?
        Configuration config = assembler.getConfiguration();            
        assertTrue(config.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

I don't know yet what dependencies I'll end with. I don't know how I'm gonna write all that stuff yet and so on.
What should I put in this test to make it valid? Should I mock something? If so how to define those dependencies?

If you could please show me the path to go with this, write some plan, some tests skeletons, what to do and in what order it'd be super-cool. I know it's a lot of writing, so maybe you can point me to any resources? All the resources about outside-in approach I've found were about simple cases with no dependencies etc.

And two questions to mocking approach.

- if mocking is about interactions and their verification, does it mean that there should not be state assertions in such tests (only mock verifications) ?
- if we replace something that doesn't exist yet with mock just for test, do we replace it later with real version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that's indeed a lot of stuff. Let's start from the end:

- Mocking is not only about 'interactions and their verification', this would be only one half of the story. In fact, you're using it in two different ways:

  1. Checking, if a certain call was made, and eventually also checking the arguments of the call (this is the 'interactions and verification' part).
  2. Using mocks to replace dependencies of the class-under-test (CUT), eventually setting up return values on the mock objects as required. Here, you use mock objects to isolate the CUT from the rest of the system (so that you can handle the CUT as an isolated 'unit', which sort of runs in a sandbox).

I'd call the first form dynamic or 'interaction-based' unit testing, it uses the Mocking frameworks call verification methods. The second one is more traditional, 'static' unit testing which asserts a fact.

- You shouldn't ever have the need to 'replace something that doesn't exist yet' (apart from the fact that this is - logically seen - completely impossible). If you feel like you need to do this, then this is a clear indication that you're trying to make the second step before the first.
- Regarding your notion of 'outside-in approach': To be honest, I've never heard of this before, so it doesn't seem to be a very prominent concept - and obviously not a very helpful one, because it seems to confuse things more than clarifying them (at least for the moment).

Now onto your first question: (*What test should I start with?*):

1. First things first - you need some mechanism to read the configuration values from file and database, and this functionality should be encapsulated in separate helper classes (you need, among other things, a clean [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for effectively doing TDD - this usually is totally underemphasized when introducing TDD/BDD). I'd suggest an interface (e.g. `IConfigurationReader`) which has two implementations (one for the file stuff and one for the database, e.g. `FileConfigurationReader` and `DatabaseConfigurationReader`). In TDD (not necessarily with a BDD approach) you would also have corresponding test fixtures. These fixtures would cover test cases like '*What happens if the underlying data store contains no/invalid/valid/other special values?*'. This is what I'd advice you to start with.
2. Only then - with the reading mechanism in operation and your `ConfigurationAssembler` class having the necessary dependencies - you would start to write tests for/implement the `ConfigurationAssembler` class. Your test then could look like this (Because I'm a C#/.NET guy, I don't know the appropriate Java tools. So I'm using pseudo-code here):

   class ConfigurationAssemblerTest {

   ```
   @Test
   public void itShouldResultWithEmptyConfigurationWhenBothSourcesAreEmpty() {

       IConfigurationReader fileConfigMock = new [Mock of FileConfigurationReader];
       fileConfigMock.[WhenAskedForConfigValues].[ReturnEmpty];

       IConfigurationReader dbConfigMock = new [Mock of DatabaseConfigurationReader];
       dbConfigMock.[WhenAskedForConfigValues].[ReturnEmpty];

       ConfigurationAssembler assembler = new ConfigurationAssembler(fileConfigMock, dbConfigMock);            

       Configuration config = assembler.getConfiguration();            

       assertTrue(config.isEmpty());
   }
   ```

   }

Two things are important here:

- The two reader objects are injected to the `ConfigurationAssembler` from outside via its constructor - this technique is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It is very helpful and important architectural principle, which generally leads to a better and cleaner architecture (and greatly helps in unit testing, especially when using mock objects).
- The test now asserts exactly what it states: The `ConfigurationAssembler` returns ('assembles') an empty config when the underlying reading mechanisms on their part return an empty result set. And because we're using mock objects to provide the config values, the test runs in complete isolation. We can be sure that we're testing only the correct functioning of the `ConfigurationAssembler` class (its handling of empty values, namely), and nothing else.

Oh, and maybe it's easier for you to start with TDD instead of BDD, because BDD is only a subset of TDD and builds on top of the concepts of TDD. So you can only do (and understand) BDD effectively when you know TDD.

HTH!